# How to disable scripts in "upload" folder using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to disable scripts in "upload" folder using .htaccess ?

Comment: any reason why you would insist on using htaccess for this rather then the server config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line:
`RemoveHandler .php`